# Batch File to Move 1st of Month to subfolder and delete the rest older than 30 days

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that does the first part perfect, but the delete part it goes and deletes everything in the entire main folder and subfolders older than 30 days. I need to move all files dated the first of the month to the 1st_of_the_Month subfolder and keep everything from the last 30 days. Here is my code:

```
net use Z: \\shared\Operations\Analytics\ActivityReports

forfiles /p Z: /m *_01.xlsx /C "cmd /c move @path \1st_of_Month_Reports"

forfiles /p Z: /s /m *.xlsx /D -30 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

I thought I nailed it, but obvious the second command is not discriminating. How do I keep the "\shared\Operations\Analytics\ActivityReports\1st_of_Month_Reports" subfolder from being cleaned out? I know one option is copy everything somewhere else, but there are years worth of archived files that average 25MB each. Is there additional code for the second command that could exclude named subfolders?

And we are using a network shared drive.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `forfiles /?` and read the output usage help. There should be used in a batch file the fully qualified file names of executables which is `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` instead of just `forfiles` and `%ComSpec%` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` instead of just `cmd`. There should be used also the __cmd__ option `/D` left to `/c` to avoid unnecessary registry accesses.

Comment: The described problem is caused by using the __forfiles__ option `/s` to search also in all subdirectories of the current directory on `Z:` which can be any directory on network drive `Z:` because of ``\`` missing on parameter `Z:` to specify explicitly the root directory of the network drive. I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). `\1st_of_Month_Reports` references the directory `1st_of_Month_Reports` in __root directory of CURRENT drive__ which can be any drive.

Comment: It would be perhaps better to use `Z:\1st_of_Month_Reports` to define on which drive the directory exists instead of hoping that the current drive is the network drive `Z:`. The __forfiles__ option `/D -30` means older than __29__ days and __not__ older than *30* days as described by you. The __forfiles__ usage help describes for option `/D` with a minus value: "__less than or equal to__ (-) *the current date minus "dd" days*" which means 30 days or older and not older than 30 days.

Comment: @Mofi - I sincerely thank you for your thorough reply. I am new to using Batch files and "ForFiles." For the most of my work, I only have a batch file that deletes the *.bak files that are generated from an Alteryx workflow. However, I have been given old projects where the archiving process was not implemented so I am just looking for a batch file that I can initiate manually when needed. Again, thank your time to explain this above.

Answer (score 0):

With all of Mofi's input, I explored with my original batch coding and discovered that by removing the "/s" on the third line worked. This kept the script from searching all the subfolders I have which solved my problem. My final batch code is this:

```
net use Z: \\shared\Operations\Analytics\ActivityReports
forfiles /p Z: /m *_01.xlsx /C "cmd /c move @path \1st_of_Month_Reports"
forfiles /p Z: /m *.xlsx /D -30 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```